# Make state checkout field required for a Vietnam country in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

The country of Vietnam in WooCommerce does not have defined states, so I
added some states to my checkout page.

This is my code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_states', 'vietnam_cities_woocommerce' );
   function vietnam_cities_woocommerce( $states ) {
     $states['VN'] = array(
      'HCM' => __('Hồ Chí Minh', 'woocommerce') ,
      'HANOI' => __('Hà Nội', 'woocommerce') ,
      'HAIPHONG' => __('Hải Phòng', 'woocommerce') ,
           );
      return $states;
}
```

It do work as I would like, but it is an optional field for Vietnam.

How to make this state field as required for Vietnam?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function will make for Vietnam the state field as a required in woocommerce:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_country_locale', 'custom_country_locale', 10, 1 );
function custom_country_locale( $locale ) {
    $locale['VN']['state']['required'] = true;

    return $locale;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

> **Explanations:** Each country have specific "locale" fields settings in WooCommerce. We are adding/altering the default WooCommerce country locale settings that are defined on [`WC_Countries` `get_country_locale()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Countries.html#11-1333)

Comment: Hi Löic, I guess that a lot of things might have changed since you posted this, would you help me on applying this exact same thing but on today's woocommerce? I tried to apply above code, but it just simply ignores it, it does not show up any error, but it does not work.