# Make state checkout field optional in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, state, checkout

Since Woo 3.5.1 the billing state field is mandatory for certain countries and I'm trying to figure out how to not make it mandatory.

This is the code I'm using, which is not working. It seems to be a core change and I don't know if there's a new hook for it?

Code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'remove_mandatory_state_billing', 10, 1 );
function remove_mandatory_state_billing( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['billing_state']['required'] = false;
    return $address_fields;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_fields', 'remove_mandatory_state_shipping', 10, 1 );
function remove_mandatory_state_shipping( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['shipping_state']['required'] = false;
    return $address_fields;
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will make the state field optional for all countries in Woocommerce:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_country_locale', 'custom_country_locale_state_optional', 10, 1 );
function custom_country_locale_state_optional( $locale ) {
    foreach( $locale as $country_code => $state_field ) {
        if( isset($locale[$country_code]['state']) ) {
            $locale[$country_code]['state']['required'] = false;
        }
    }
    return $locale;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

Related: [Make state checkout field required for a specific country in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53137583/make-state-checkout-field-required-for-a-specific-country-in-woocommerce/53139575#53139575)

Comment: I tried both of the above code none of them are working..