# Make postcode checkout field required for Ireland in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

In WooCommerce checkout page I'm looking to change the postcode field (Irish Eircode) to being a required field, by default this is an optional field when the selected country is Ireland. I just want to know is there a way to change this to required and to have a little red star beside the "Eircode" to signify that it is a required field.

The screenshot below should give a clear idea of what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Note that not all Irish addresses have an eircode. (I believe that they're assigned once a quarter, so newbuilt houses don't yet have them; nor do building sites, who may also want to order deliveries).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Ireland "postcode" field you need to alter the default WooCommerce country locale settings that are defined on [`WC_Countries` `get_country_locale()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Countries.html#11-1333) as follow *(on lines 950 to 958)*:

```
'IE' => array(
    'postcode' => array(
        'required' => false,
        'label'    => __( 'Eircode', 'woocommerce' ),
    ),
    'state'    => array(
        'label' => __( 'County', 'woocommerce' ),
    ),
),
```

So using the following hooked function you can make the `postcode` field required:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_country_locale', 'ireland_country_locale_change', 10, 1 );
function ireland_country_locale_change( $locale ) {
    $locale['IE']['postcode']['required'] = true;

    return $locale;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

Similar answer: [Make state checkout field required for a specific country in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53137583/make-state-checkout-field-required-for-a-specific-country-in-woocommerce/53139575#53139575)